# Optimize web calculating to speedup web

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My system is as follow

[image]

right now, I developed website about **monitoring sales**. Manager will give sales a target each product.. Then sales can input realisation of selling and manager will approve. Web will calculate the achievement and display sales who get the best achiev. Case Preview like in picture.
If the sales about 10 or 20 person its not problem.. But if the sales more than 100 sales like my case in web the sales  man about 130 person and 700 approve selling, the result is my web very slow to calculate the best sales and now the sale product still increase.
I use php and CI.
Please give me suggest the best way to solve the problem like this

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Performance View in 1 query:

```
SELECT sales, (avg( percent_sold )*100) avg_percent_sold
FROM (
    SELECT sales, product, SUM(selling) sum_sold, target, SUM(selling)/target as percent_sold
    FROM (
        SELECT tt.sales, tt.product,  tt.target, IFNULL(ts.selling,0) as selling
        FROM tbl_target tt
        LEFT JOIN tbl_selling ts  ON ( ts.sales=tt.sales AND ts.product=tt.product )
        ORDER BY NULL
    ) tbl_sales
    GROUP BY sales, product
    ORDER BY NULL
) tbl_performance
GROUP BY sales
ORDER BY avg_percent_sold desc
```

Performance can be optimized by adding indexes on all columns of tbl_target and tbl_selling . Make sure to check using the `EXPLAIN` query command to find out where indexes are not optimal.

Comment: Thanks so much for reply kevin.. Can you give some example how i make indexes in the table or how it looks in the table? And how i use EXPLAIN? For information i use Codeigniter and PHP.

Comment: Use `CREATE INDEX` query directly in MySQL in order to create indexes. For your tables, here are the indexes I would recommend you create: `CREATE INDEX target_index
ON tbl_target (sales, product, target)` and `CREATE INDEX selling_index
ON tbl_selling (sales, product, selling)`. Here is a great tutorial on how to optimize your MySQL table with indexes and explain tool: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/three-easy-ways-to-optimize-your-mysql-queries/